# Jasmine HTTP tests not getting coverage on RXJS pipeline

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, jasmine, rxjs

#### Problem

Hey everyone, I'm adding some Karma-Jasmine unit-testing to my Angular 2 project and I cannot for the life of me get the coverage to hit the RXJS operators in my service methods.

The tests are using the HttpClientTestingModule and HttpTestingController.

#### Code

Here's a simple example just using the map operator.

MyService:

```
getAssetCount(): Observable<AssetModel[]> {
  return this.http
    .get('/myproject/v1/asset-count')
    .pipe(map(response => response as AssetModel[]));
}
```

MyService.spec:

```
service = testBed.get(MyService);
httpMock = testBed.get(HttpTestingController);
...

it('should getAssetCount', () => {
  const dummyResponse = [{...}];
  service.getAssetCount().subscribe((response: AssetModel[]) => {
    expect(response).toEqual(dummyResponse);
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(
      '/myproject/v1/asset-count'
    );
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    req.flush(dummyResponse);
    httpMock.verify();
  });
});
```

#### Result

The resulting coverage:

[image: The resulting coverage]

I would have thought having a subscription to the observable in the test would trigger the *map()* call, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding how these mock services work.

From looking around, it seems like switching to the **XHRBackend** instead of the HttpClientTestingModule to generate dummy 200/404/etc responses could solve the issue, but besides being more boilerplate, it seems like most people were suggesting to use the TestingModule instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try moving the `flush()` and other testing logic outside of the subscribe, just leaving the expect(response) inside.  Something like this:

```
it('should getAssetCount', () => {
  const dummyResponse = [{...}];
  service.getAssetCount().subscribe((response: AssetModel[]) => {
    expect(response).toEqual(dummyResponse);
  });
  const req = httpMock.expectOne(
    '/myproject/v1/asset-count'
  );
  expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
  req.flush(dummyResponse);
  httpMock.verify();
});
```

Comment: Ah I don't even remember putting those methods in the subscribe - that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted.  :)